# inotify problems when running system

Tags: c++, c, inotifypropertychanged

I want to monitor a folder.

Every time a notification pops up i want to run a system command line. 
Problems when using system command. Each new event pops up 3 times though it should pop up one time. 
EDIT:
Thx for you replays. I found the bug. The system executed a folder that was inside the monitored foder. this is why each time i dropped a foder in the monitored folder, the event was printed 3 times.

code-----------

```
    /*

    Simple example for inotify in Linux.

    */


    #include <sys/inotify.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(){
        int fd,wd,wd1,i=0,len=0;
        char pathname[100],buf[1024];
        struct inotify_event *event;

        fd=inotify_init1(IN_NONBLOCK);
        /* watch /test directory for any activity and report it back to me */

 `wd=inotify_add_watch(fd,"/home/folder",IN_ALL_EVENTS`);

        while(1){
            //read 1024  bytes of events from fd into buf
            i=0;
            len=read(fd,buf,1024);
            while(i<len){
                event=(struct inotify_event *) &buf[i];


                /* check for changes */
                if(event->mask & IN_OPEN)
                 {  // printf("\n %s :was opened\n",event->name);
                    char*path="/home/folder/";
                    char*file=event->name;
                    int n=sizeof(path)+sizeof(file);
                    char *result=(char *)malloc(512);
                    strcpy(result,path); // copy string one into the result.
                    strcat(result,file); // append string two to the result
                    puts (result);

                    //printf("RESUULT:");

                    int pp=sizeof(result);
                    char *run="/home/test/./userr ";
                    int l=sizeof(run);

                    char *cmd=(char *)malloc(1000);
                    strcpy(cmd,run);
                    strcat(cmd,result);
                    puts (cmd);

                    system(cmd);
                    printf("\n %s :was opened\n",event->name);
                    //break;

            }
                if(event->mask & IN_MODIFY)
                      printf("%s : modified\n",event->name);

                if(event->mask & IN_ATTRIB)
                      printf("%s :meta data changed\n",event->name);

                if(event->mask & IN_ACCESS)
                      printf("%s :was read\n",event->name);

                if(event->mask & IN_CLOSE_WRITE)
                      printf("%s :file opened for writing was closed\n",event->name);

               // if(event->mask & IN_DELETE)
                //    printf("%s :deleted\n",event->name);

                /* update index to start of next event */
                i+=sizeof(struct inotify_event)+event->len;
            }

        }

    }
```

EDIT:

HOW CAN I PUT TO SLEEP THE WHILE(1) FOR 1 MINUTE?
SPEEP(60); pops the inotify void:was opened instead of folder1:was opened when i dropp a foder in the monitored folder

./exec

```
 :was opened
/home/folder/
   :file opened not for writing was closed
```

Without sleep inside while (the code posted) i have:

```
 1002_copy :was opened
/home/folder/1002_copy
1002_copy :file opened not for writing was closed
```

Comment: There is a break in the first if(){} block. i will not be incremented after this block, and it will skip the rest of what has been read. Hint: use a for(;;) loop, which is clearer.

Comment: i've added break because i need to. but it's not working

Comment: @justAngela But, what about the outer while(1) loop. That will cause the execution of inner loop again. See my answer.

Comment: Break only breaks out of the inner loop (which makes no sense). You are calling this program from another program, using system() ?

Comment: inotify should monitor a folder as long as you wish. i want to execute another program when i drop a file inside the monitored folder. problem appears when execute the executable. it execute it infinite times, but i dont want that. i just want to execute it in the moment i drop a file in my monitord folder.

Comment: Please restate your problem. It is natural that your program runs forever, since its outer while(1) loop is unbreakable. Is is also possible that you are missing events, because you break out of the inner loop before the buf[] is exhausted (at least you don't chek for it)

Comment: @wildplasser but the system command should be executed when i drop a file in the monitored folder. in my case that doesn't happen. is like th inotify sees i'm dropping file after file. if i comment system("") everything works ok (the evens pop up just in the moment i drop a file inside the folder)

Comment: Maybe the progam or script `home/test/userr` is not reacheable or executable by the user that runs the inotify-thing. Maybe you could check system()s return value and errno ?

Comment: the system command is executed properly, because it returns the values i expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running `system()` in the if condition which is called every time a open file is seen.

So, it will run infinitely whenever you open a file. You have to find a way to get out of the loop.

When execution reaches the line break, it breaks out of the inner while but what about the outer `while(1)`?

AS REQUESTED (working code):

```
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int fd,wd,wd1,i=0,len=0;
    char pathname[100],buf[1024];
    struct inotify_event *event;

    fd=inotify_init1(IN_NONBLOCK);
    wd=inotify_add_watch(fd,"/tmp/temp",IN_ALL_EVENTS);
    while(1){
        //read 1024  bytes of events from fd into buf
        i=0;
        len=read(fd,buf,1024);
        while(i<len){
            event=(struct inotify_event *) &buf[i];
            /* check for changes */
            if(event->mask & IN_CREATE){
                system("/bin/date");
            }
            i+=sizeof(struct inotify_event)+event->len;
        }  
    }
}
```

The above code executes $date command each time a file is added to /tmp/temp. Modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: but i don't want to go out from loop. i am using inotify..it monitor a floder is there is a drop in it. so that while is needed

Comment: @justAngela It's stripped down version of your code. The 2 while loops. The if condition is the part (in IN_OPEN) where you use a system() call.

Comment: thx for replay. How to do this if i want to run system every time i drop a file inside the monitor folder/

Comment: Surely the code above will only execute the first time something is opened? So if the OP drops another file in, they won't see that second event?

Comment: thx for replay. I need to execute the executable every time i drop a file inside my monitored folder. how to do that? seems my code doesn't work correctly

Comment: How can I put to sleep the application for 1 minutes? I've tried to put set sleep(60) but now when a new event pops up instead showing eg: folder1: was opened it appeard void: was opened

Comment: @justAngela Why did you edit the post. It would make all the answers irrelevant. Revert back & for a wider audience ask the new question again if you want.

Answer (score 1):

What is your system command doing? Is it opening the file you're changing? If so, wouldn't that cause your code to run again and put you into an infinite loop (which is apparently what you're seeing)?

**Edit** - There's [an article in Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8478?page=0,3) which is doing something very similar to you. I noticed they're using a larger buffer and the comments mention something about structure alignment so is it possible you're getting a bad event length which is causing a buffer overrun and forcing your code to loop for longer than expected.

Ether way, I'd check (with a bit of printf debug logic) that you're looping as expected.